# Проблема с годами раньше 100 в javascript

Tags: javascript, дата

Задание: создать страницу, которая запрашивает дату и выводит количество дней, которое прошло с этой даты.

Для годов позже 100-го проблем никаких нет, а для годов ранее js считает их как года из диапазона 1900-1999.

Как исправить?

```js
let y = prompt('Введите год');
let year = parseInt(y);

let m = prompt('Введите номер месяца: ');
let month = parseInt(m);

let d = prompt('Введите день: ');
let day = parseInt(d);

let today = new Date();
let currentYear = today.getFullYear();
let current = today.getTime();

let birth = new Date(year, month - 1, day).getTime();
let age = current - birth;

let result = Math.floor(age / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

if (day > 0 && day <= 31 && month > 0 && month <= 12 && year > 0 && year <= currentYear) {
  document.write('Прошло ' + result + ' дней');
} else {
  console.log('Ошибка в данных');
}
```

Comment: Пример ввода и вывода?

Comment: `let birth = new Date(year, month-1, day).getTime();` почему тут манс - 1?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date: `year` - Целое значение, представляющее год. Значения с 0 по 99 отображаются на года с 1900 по 1999

Comment: @letUser скорее всего, потому что пользователи обычно вводят от 1 до 12, а `Date` принимает от 0 до 11

Answer (score 2):

```js
let year = 90,
  month = 12,
  day = 5

let today = new Date(),
  currentYear = today.getFullYear(),
  current = today.getTime()

let birth = new Date(year, month - 1, day)
// установило правильно :)
birth.setFullYear(year)
console.log('birth', birth)
let age = current - birth.getTime()

let result = Math.floor(age / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

if (day > 0 && day <= 31 && month > 0 && month <= 12 && year > 0 && year <= currentYear) {
  document.write('Прошло ' + result + ' дней');
} else {
  console.log('Ошибка в данных');
}
```